# CakePHP 3.x - fixtures import does not load data

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, fixture

I am trying to import fixtures in my CakePHP 3.x plugin. 
When I launch the tests, I always get the error :

> UserManager\Test\TestCase\Controller\UsersControllerTest::testProfile
>   exception 'Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException' with message 'Record not found in table "users"

Here is UsersFixture.php :

```
namespace UserManager\Test\Fixture;
use Cake\TestSuite\Fixture\TestFixture;

class UsersFixture extends TestFixture {
    public $import = ['table' => 'users'];
}
```

My test fails because it can not find the current user in test database.

I supposed that users table is created successfully, but no data are imported.

Of course, many users are recorded in my existing users table, and the tested user id is one of these records.

My testIndex() method fails too, because number of records is always equal to 0.

Why does the fixtures table not contain my records ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think there's nothing wrong with your code. From what I can see,  CakePHP 3.x does **not** support the importation of table entries in the fixtures anymore, only the table structure.

(See doc differences: 2.x: [Importing table information **and records**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html#importing-table-information-and-records), 3.x: [Importing table information](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html#importing-table-information))

I don't think there's any way around it, unless you modify CakePHP 3.x core directly.

Comment: Great thanks to you ! I think 3.x french translation contains mistakes, speaking of "Importer les informations de table et les enregistrements".

Answer (score 9):

You can certainly import records in cake 3.

From cake bake `bin/cake bake fixture invoice_statuses -r --count 100`
You would need to regenerate this every time you make changes to the table but it is better than nothing. Gives you a nice starting point.

You can also use conditions to generate very specific fixtures.

[image]

Comment: Apparently the argument list was changed, here's what the bake fixture source looks like at the moment of writing: [src/Shell/Task/FixtureTask.php#L66](https://github.com/cakephp/bake/blob/b2cd43ea2a20da7298e4bda647759895056e7473/src/Shell/Task/FixtureTask.php#L66)