# Cakephp 3 Test: How to load records from database?

Tags: php, cakephp, testing, cakephp-3.0

I need to test some reports, there is a complex data structure and a lot of data affect for those reports, so creating fixtures for this purpose would be very tedious work. I'd like to use an existing database (actually copy of it) to test reports.

How can I achieve this in cakephp 3 tests? 
Is it possible to load records for fixtures (not a structure of table) from database in cakephp 3?

Answer (score 7):

You can create fixtures from existing records in your tables using the **Bake** utility:

```
    --records, -r     Generate a fixture with records from the non-test
                      database. Used with --count and --conditions to limit
                      which records are added to the fixture.
    --count, -n       When using generated data, the number of records to
                      include in the fixture(s). (default:
                      1)
```

#### For example:

```sh
cake bake fixture you_table_name -r -n 100
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there a solution to use the database directly without fixtures? I've dumped "real" database and created a separate database from it for this purpose (test reports), but there are a lot of records (thousands), so I think generating fixtures from those records is not a good idea.

Comment: This might also help some people loading records. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33789238/711401

Answer (score 0):

Since PHPUnit deletes everything from the database that it has access to between each test, you probably don't want to give it access to your production database.

The solution you're looking for is probably writing each fixture's `init()` function to build its `$records` property from data it pulls from the production database.

Like this (unverified):

```
public function init()
{
    $thingsTable = TableRegistry::get('Things');
    $this->records = $thingsTable->find()->toArray();
    parent::init();
}
```

Note that this will really slow down your tests, though caching the results will mitigate that.